# Multiple Photos upload on Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to upload multiple photos together on facebook...
I have uploaded a single photo at a time using GraphAPI....but not multiple...
Please suggest...
Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place a "batched" request to the Graph API. This is documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/ (check out the paragraph "Uploading binary data"). Basically it's a cURL call where you json encode an array containing all the "batched" requests ("batch=[json array of calls]"). For some good reson Facebook limits your array to 20 requests. It translates pretty nicely to the PHP cURL methods, if you've got cURL enabled on your server...

```
curl 
 –F  'access_token=…' \
 -F  'batch=[{"method":"POST", \
              "relative_url":"me/photos", \
              "body":"message=My cat photo" \
              "attached_files":"file1" \
             },
             {"method":"POST", \
              "relative_url":"me/photos", \
              "body":"message=My dog photo" \
              "attached_files":"file2" \
             },
            ]’
 -F  'file1=@cat.gif' \
 -F 'file2=@dog.jpg' \
https://graph.facebook.com
```

**UPDATE:** replaced “ with " and ‘ with '

Comment: I replaced “ with " and ‘ with ', this might be a reason for the code not working. But anyway, I'm doing batched requests over PHP cURL, just like in the example, and it worked in my case.

Comment: ok, finally got working after replacing the '\n' with ' '. That causes the issue while evaluating with php.