# Issue in uploading images on Facebook using batch JSON process in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Now my i trying to use batch method for sending multiple methods, so i used following code for trying to send two images on Facebook using FBGraph,

```
NSString *req01 = @"{ \"method\": \"POST\", \"relative_url\": \"me/photos\", \"body\": \"message=MyMessageOnPhotoone\", \"attached_files\": \"myimagedata\"}";
NSString *req02 = @"{ \"method\": \"POST\", \"relative_url\": \"me/photos\", \"body\": \"message=MyMessageOnPhototwo\", \"attached_files\": \"myimagedata\"}";
NSString *allRequests = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[ %@, %@ ]", req01, req02];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:allRequests forKey:@"batch"];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

And batch method is,

```
curl 
–F  'access_token=…' \
-F  'batch=[{"method":"POST", \
          "relative_url":"me/photos", \
          "body":"message=My cat photo" \
          "attached_files":"file1" \
         },
         {"method":"POST", \
          "relative_url":"me/photos", \
          "body":"message=My dog photo" \
          "attached_files":"file2" \
         },
        ]’
     -F  'file1=@cat.gif' \
     -F 'file2=@dog.jpg' \
     https://graph.facebook.com
```

I got following error,

```
  (
    {
    my binary image encoded data
    code = 400;
    headers =         (
                    {
            name = "WWW-Authenticate";

           my binary image encoded data
        },
                    {
            name = "HTTP/1.1";
            value = "400 Bad Request";
        },
                    {
            name = "Cache-Control";
            value = "no-store";
        },
                    {
            name = "Content-Type";
            value = "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8";
        }
    );
},
    {

     myimage binary encoded data
    code = 400;
    headers =         (
                    {
            name = "WWW-Authenticate";
            myimageBinary encoded data
        },
                    {
            name = "HTTP/1.1";
            value = "400 Bad Request";
        },
                    {
            name = "Cache-Control";
            value = "no-store";
        },
                    {
            name = "Content-Type";
            value = "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8";
        }
    );
   }
  )
```

I can't able to rectify the problem is in URL request in my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498302/multiple-photos-upload-on-facebook

Comment: how about simple loop through you images array? send one at the time?

Comment: @Muhaye, i want to send array of images

Comment: @iHungry Sorry I don't think u can do it just by sending an array https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos

Comment: @Muhaye, i want to send multiple images. Suppose i m not using array of images then?

Comment: @iHungry the previous code was fine, you just needed to call it within a loop in other to send many photos

Comment: @Muhaye, actually i do not want to upload images one by one using looping. It totally non conceptual because when you upload one image and waiting for completion process of your request and uploading image after that you start another request for other images. So instead of batch process is very suitable actually. Using just small stub of code sending multiple streams at a time and also it avoiding looping.